# Why the value of the tag isn't outputted

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new in XSLT and I don't understand the basic idea of templates.
I am doing an experiment to see if the output is what I expect. Unfortunately not. This are the files in transformation:

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <continent>America</continent>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>Bulgaria</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

And this is the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//continent"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//continent">
        <xsl:value-of select="continent"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is empty sheet. I expect the value of the continent tag to be printed, namely `America`. Please shed some light on this matter. Thank tou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error lies here:

```
<xsl:template match="//continent">
    <xsl:value-of select="continent"/>
</xsl:template>
```

In this template, you have matched a `<continent>`, and with `<xsl:value-of select="continent" />` you try to retrieve information from another `<continent>` child tag (which do not exist).

If you use `<xsl:value-of select="."/>`, `<xsl:value-of select="text()"/>` or even `<xsl:apply-templates />`, you should obtain the desired output.